# allow normal User to modify HKLM registry Key on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a local user of a windows Server 2008 that is a member of builtin Users group, a program that run this user need to have write access to a Key located in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, can i enable this user to have write access in HKLM without adding it to Administrators group ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can even be specific enough to grant users read/write permissions for only that softwares key. When changing only 1 or a few permissions using regedit is fine, simply right click on the key and alter permissions exactly the same as changing NTFS permissions

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245031 has some more details about scripting permission changes, which will be important if you want to roll out changes to multiple machines.